# How to upload profile picture in unity3d from gallery

Tags: unity-game-engine, server

Code:

```
   IEnumerator PickImage (int maxSize)
{
    Texture2D texture = null;
    NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.GetImageFromGallery (( path) => {
        Debug.Log ("Image path: " + path);
        if (path != null) {
            // Create Texture from selected image
            texture = NativeGallery.LoadImageAtPath (path, maxSize);
            if (texture == null) {
                Debug.Log ("Couldn't load texture from " + path);
                return;
            }

            profileImage.sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f), 100f);
        }
    }, "Select an image", "image/*", maxSize);

    if (texture != null) {

        // make texture read and write able
        Texture2D readableTexture = DuplicateTexture(texture);
        Debug.Log ("readable texture width: " + readableTexture.width + " height: " + readableTexture.height);

        WWWForm form = new WWWForm ();
        Debug.Log ("player id: " + DataCollection.localPlayer.PlayerId);
        form.AddField (GameConstants.ARG_UPLOAD_PHOTO_PLAYER_ID, DataCollection.localPlayer.PlayerId);
        form.AddBinaryData (GameConstants.ARG_UPLOAD_PHOTO, readableTexture.GetRawTextureData (), "profilepic.jpg", "image/*");

        Dictionary<string,string> headerDisc = form.headers;

        WWW www = new WWW (GameConstants.API_UPLOAD_PHOTO, form.data, headerDisc);
        yield return www;

        if (www.error == null) {

            Debug.Log ("Data: " + www.text);
            profileImage.sprite = Sprite.Create (texture, new Rect (0f, 0f, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2 (0.5f, 0.5f), 100f);

        } else {
            Debug.Log ("Error: " + www.error);
        }

    }
    Debug.Log ("Permission result: " + permission);
}
```

Comment: Instead of only posting your code .. could you state clearly where exactly your issue lies? Any errors? What exactly doesn't behave as expected?

Comment: Title updated, tag removed

Comment: i am trying to upload the profile pic on a Api but i am unable upload it .error is texture is not readable please make it readable in import settings.